# Backup of All websites with MSDeploy

Tags: iis, backup, msdeploy

I am trying to make a command line argument that will backup all my websites to a file which I can then move periodically to offsite backup location.
I would need all the content and all the settings so in case of a server fault I can easily restore the setup again quickly.

I found this command
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:appHostConfig='DefaultWebsite',computerName=server1 -dest:package='defaultWebsiteBackup.zip' -enableLink:AppPoolExtension

This looks nice and all, but I would need to make a command for each website.
Is there a way to backup all sites (and future sites) in the same command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webServer,computerName=server1 -dest:package='defaultWebsiteBackup.zip',encryptPassword=password123
```

The `-source:webServer` does a complete backup of everything. App pools and other config values, including SSL certs (if you have any). The `encryptPassword` is required if you have SSL certs.

Comment: Also,  -enableLink:AppPoolExtension adds some info about the app pool.